# Ngnix issue caching image with magmi importing

Tags: import, image, magento-2.0, magmi, magento-2.0.6

I have used magmi tool to import product images on Magento 2.0.6.

There is one option is to replace the images if it exists.

I have check that option, 
it uploads the file successfully physically (I use transmit to go to the server to check that).

But i view it on the web it still display the old image, not the image i have just imported.

I know it is the cache issue, i have already tried to flush and clear all the cache that i know : redis cache, magento caches.

Are there any caches that i am missing here? (like nginx cache because my local machine using apache and it works fine)

Comment: what stops you from reloading nginx and also check your server config???